# Autosave to user desktop generates File Format Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a product creation template which is filled by other users.

I have two problems.

First I'd like to save the file to the user's desktop with predefined name. I wrote similar code in Excel 2010. In Excel 2013 file paths are different. So I have to extract user's desktop path, they can use PC with other languages so I'm not sure whether below code will work.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
```

Second I want to save as "xlsm" and when I changed the file extension to ".xlsm" it didn't save.

My Excel 2010 code;

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Environ$("UserProfile") & "\My Documents\" & _
  Environ$("UserName") & " - " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mmm-dd") & ".xls"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of the [Workbook.SaveAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) and you will see that `.SaveAs` has a `FileFormat` parameter (also see [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel)).

Accordingly you must use

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ$("UserProfile") & "\My Documents\" & _ 
    Environ$("UserName") & " - " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mmm-dd") & ".xlsm", _ 
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: @user3551927 the desktop path is `DesktopPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"`

Comment: Hi, my problem is what if users Windows have different language then English?

Comment: Is this is only a hypothetical question or a real practical issue? The desktop folder is named `Desktop` in all localizations of Windows if I'm not totally wrong. So that should be no issue.

Comment: at the moment hypothetical, I can't check it with another user at the moment. thanks for your help and have a nice day